# sql loader associating variable number physical records with a single physical record

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I have the following data:

```
Aapple mango wood
Bpine tea orange
Bnuts blots match
Ajust another record
```

Now I want every record beginning with 'A' to be associated with record beginning with 'B' until another 'A' record or non-'B' record is encountered.
For example from the above data,
I would like to retrieve the following data(2 records),

```
mango tea
mango blots
```

The number of B records following an A record is variable, that is,(A record might be followed by any number of B records(3 in the data below).

```
Aapple mango wood
Bpine tea orange
Bnuts blots match
Basdf asdf  asdf
Ajust another record
```

So the resulting output would be

```
mango tea
mango blots
mango asdf
```

Is it possible to do the above using sql loader?. Any help/pointers would be most welcome.

Edit:
I was thinking about using `CONTINUEIF` clause, but there doesn't seem to be way to eliminate the records that was retrieved earlier.
For example, if I use,

```
CONTINUEIF NEXT PRESERVE(1)='B'
```

I would get "mango tea blots asdf" in one go and not

```
"mango|tea"
"mango|blots"
"mango|asdf"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i would load the records to 2 seperate tables based on the record type identifier,
see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_control_file.htm#i1005614

and use recnum to preserve the order

see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch06.htm

you can then transform the data in sql

```
SELECT 
    a.text,
    b.text,
    a.id,
    a.nxtid 
FROM 
(
    SELECT text,id, NVL(LEAD(seq,1) OVER (ORDER BY id),999999) AS NXTID
    FROM t1
) a
LEFT JOIN t2 B ON b.seq > a.id AND b.id < a.nxtid
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way to do this without the SQL. ie., purely using SQL loader. Currently we are using PL/SQL to load the files using UTL_FILE and we are looking to improve the performance by using SQL loader.

Comment: Not that I know of. At least this way you have a single set based operation rather than row based so it should be quicker.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. As I couldn't find any other solutions for this, I am marking yours as the correct answer.